# How do I edit a singular value in a JSON file with Node.JS/Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm making a discord bot with discord.js and I have a system that I have the ability to turn off and on by changing a value in a JSON file from true to false and vice versa. I created a command that allows moderators in discord to turn that system on and off. This is where my question comes in. In that JSON file, I have 2 values.

One is an array that holds different strings with which the system will randomly pick to send a message back into the discord

and the 2nd value is just a boolean called `timedStatus` and it's set to either true or false to turn the system on and off. I was wondering how I can change **JUST** that value without affecting the array. I've done something similar to this before but I just can not remember how to do it.

This is my code for the command.

```js
if (cmd === prefix + "timedreplies") {
        if (timedReplies.replystatus = true) {
            console.log("Timed replies set to off");
            // Set to off
        } else {
            console.log("Timed replies set to on");
            // set to on
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the value directly!

**something.json**

```json
{
  arr: ['str1', 'str2', 'str3'],
  timedStatus: false
}
```

As you can see, that’s the JSON file (I don’t know *exactly* what it looks like though)

Here we will use the `fs` module (which requires no installation) to read and write to the file.

```js
const fs = require('fs')
const file = fs.readFileSync('./something.json', 'utf8');
const data = JSON.parse(file)
data.timedStatus = true
fs.writeFileSync('./something.json', JSON.stringify(data))
```

Comment: If it doesn’t work, just comment it. I had no chance to test it.